# My listview for the products list won't allow for any interaction with the listview

Tags: java, listview

So this is my Shoppinglist application to launch the window, unfortunately the listview for the products section won't let any interaction even happen with the mouse, only arrow keys.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class ShoppingListApp extends Application {
    private GroceryItem[] GroceryList;
    ShopperListAppView1 view  = new ShopperListAppView1();
    private Shopper shopper = new Shopper();
    private Carryable item ;

    public ShoppingListApp() { GroceryList = Shopper.List1();}

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Pane aPane = new Pane();
        aPane.getChildren().add(view);

        view.getButtonPane().getBuy().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) { handleBuyButtonPress();}
        });

        view.getButtonPane().getReturnb().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) { handleReturnButtonPress();}
        });

        view.getButtonPane().getCheckout().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) { handleCheckoutButtonPress();}
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Grocery Store Application");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(aPane));
        view.update(GroceryList, 0);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void handleBuyButtonPress(){
        for (int i = 0; i < Shopper.List1().length; i++){
            if (view.getpList().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == Shopper.List1()[i].getDescription()){
                item = Shopper.List1()[i];
            }
        }
        shopper.addItem(item);
        view.update(GroceryList, 0);
    }

    private void handleReturnButtonPress(){
        for(int i = 0; i < Shopper.List1().length; i++){
            if (view.getcList().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == Shopper.List1()[i].getDescription()){
                item = Shopper.List1()[i];
            }
        }
        shopper.removeItem(item);
        view.update(GroceryList, 0);
    }

    private void handleCheckoutButtonPress(){
        shopper.computeTotalCost();
        shopper.packBags();
        view.update(GroceryList, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

And after this, is the shopping list app view, to display the window for the controllers. This also holds the update method to refresh the screen.

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class ShopperListAppView1 extends Pane implements GroceryView {
    private ListView<String> pList, sList, cList;
    private ShopperButtonPane buttonPane;
    private TextField priceText;

    public ListView<String> getpList() { return pList; }
    public ListView<String> getcList() { return cList; }
    public ListView<String> getsList() { return sList; }

    public ShopperButtonPane getButtonPane() { return buttonPane; }

    public ShopperListAppView1(){
        Label products = new Label("Product");
        products.relocate(10, 10);
        Label shoppingcart = new Label("Shopping Cart");
        shoppingcart.relocate(220,10);
        Label contents = new Label("Contents");
        contents.relocate(430, 10);
        Label price = new Label("Total Price:");
        price.setStyle("-fx-font: 12 arial; -fx-base: WHITE; -fx-text-fill: rgb(0,0,0);");
        price.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        price.relocate(565, 355);
        price.setPrefSize(65,25);

        priceText = new TextField();
        priceText.relocate(630,355);
        priceText.setPrefSize(100, 25);
        priceText.setEditable(false);

        pList = new ListView<String>();
        pList.relocate(10, 45);
        pList.setPrefSize(200, 300);

        sList = new ListView<String>();
        sList.relocate(220, 45);
        sList.setPrefSize(200, 300);

        cList = new ListView<String>();
        cList.relocate(430, 45);
        cList.setPrefSize(300, 300);

        buttonPane = new ShopperButtonPane();
        buttonPane.relocate(0, 0);
        buttonPane.setPrefSize( 540,25);

        getChildren().addAll(products, shoppingcart, contents, price, pList, cList, sList, buttonPane, priceText);

        setPrefSize(740, 390);
    }

    public void update(GroceryItem[] model, int selectedItem) {
        String[] Product = new String[Shopper.List1().length];
        String[] Cart = new String[Shopper.List1().length];
        String[] Contents = new String[Shopper.List1().length];
        Shopper shopper = new Shopper();

        for (int i = 0; i < Shopper.List1().length; i++) {
            Product[i] = model[i].toString();
            if (shopper.getCart()[i] != null){
                Cart[i] = shopper.getCart()[i].getDescription();
            }
        }

        buttonPane.getBuy().setDisable(pList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() < 0);     
        buttonPane.getReturnb().setDisable(cList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() < 0);
        buttonPane.getCheckout().setDisable(cList.hasProperties());

        priceText.setText(shopper.StringTotalCost());
        priceText.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);
        pList.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Product));
        sList.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Cart));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain, what is the current output and what is expected.